# Refused to display 'https://example.tld/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: javascript, iframe, webview

I'm making a browser extension. I have created a popup window that is opened after the user click on a button. I have a form input and an iframe, I want that when the user enter an url it will be able to display it inside the iframe but I'm facing this issue

```
Refused to display 'https://discord.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

A lot of websites will not load into the iframe and I'm not able to find a way to manage this.

What I want to achive is to have an indipendent webView that will be act like the browser and will load an url when it's inserted by the user. The iframe is the most flexible solution I think, but if anyone have any suggestion on how to implement this I will appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `X-Frame-Options` header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

The response header you are getting back from `https://discord.com/` does not allow the browser to render it inside an `<iframe>` element. This is for security reasons and you likely won't be able to find a workaround (otherwise it would be a security loophole).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've done a bit of research, and at the moment I was not able to find a way to display and embed websites in another page without iframe.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, Im also finding a way to display the discord server join page in an iframe on Next.js project.