# Angular / Keycloak X-FRAME-OPTIONS to deny

Tags: angular, keycloak, x-frame-options

Our Angular Application is protected with Keycloak.
After deplying the Application to OpenShift and then visting the URL of the Application a white screen appears and in the logs we see

```
Refused to display 'https://xxx-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.ch/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

In the keycloak documentation we found this: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#clickjacking

and after trying to implement it, the same error occurs.

Also found this resource but still no solution: [Refused to display 'https://example.tld/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64218203/refused-to-display-https-example-tld-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-opt)

By opening an incognito tab and visiting the application URL this Problem does not appear.
Is this something in combination with SSO? How can we fix this? Any suggestions ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75243024/what-makes-keycloak-angular-throw-an-error-in-this-angular-14-app/75243473#75243473