# What makes Keycloak Angular throw an error in this Angular 14 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, keycloak, angular14

I am working on an app in Angular 14 that requires authentication/authorization, reason for witch I use **[Keycloak Angular](https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular)**
.

As per the instructions, I have first installed Keycloak Angular with:

```
npm install keycloak-angular keycloak-js
```

Then in `fe\src\app\app.module.ts`:

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { KeycloakAngularModule, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './shared/material.module';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

// Components
import { ErrorsComponent } from './shared/error.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
        realm: 'demo',
        clientId: 'my-app'
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html'
      }
    });
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ErrorsComponent,
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    KeycloakAngularModule
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have also added **silent-check-sso.html** to the `src\assets\` directory.

#### The problem

At `http://localhost:4200/`, I only see a blank page and the browser throws the error:

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

#### Questions

1. What is causing this error?
2. What is the easiest and most reliable way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is  due that Keycloak will prevent a website from including any login page within an iframe. This is to prevent clickjacking attacks.

To enable this just fallow this guide from keyclock documentation: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/15.0/server_admin/, just check after "Authorizing Iframes"

[image]

And also check  if flags: checkLoginIframe is set to false.

Comment: Great, but is there any alternative to authorizing iframes?

Comment: It should be possible, as documentation shows us, there is an example for authoring goole.com for example. Hopefully this is working

Comment: Hey, i tried, pls check the comment. No worries!